# How do we select multiple columns in a sum()/group by query?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have a requirement to pull a total # of product quantity from an Access DB, but include the vendor name, id number, description, etc... along with the sum of quantity.

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT [Vendor Name], SUM([Quantity]) AS Total
FROM [SalesDB]
WHERE [Vendor No] IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) AND [Item Description] = 'bolts'
Group By [Vendor Name]
```

Works great... except I need to pull more columns in the query, something like this:

```
SELECT [Vendor Name], [Vendor No], [Item No], [Item Description], [Item Cost], [Quantity],  SUM([Quantity]) AS Total
FROM [SalesDB]
WHERE [Vendor No] IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) AND [Item Description] = 'bolts'
Group By [Vendor Name]
```

Doesn't work, throws an aggregate error

So instead do something like so:

```
SELECT [Vendor Name], [Vendor No], [Item No], [Item Description], [Item Cost], [Quantity],  SUM([Quantity]) AS Total
FROM [SalesDB]
WHERE [Vendor No] IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) AND [Item Description] = 'bolts'
Group By [Vendor Name], [Vendor No], [Item No], [Item Description], [Item Cost], [Quantity]
```

Which runs but changes the results too much. What's the appropriate way to handle this query?

Comment: As an aside, get rid of those spaces in field (column) names, if you can. They will slowly drive you nuts from typing square brackets around everything.

Comment: Definitely, if it were my DB, no way I'd have spaces. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

You have to make your first query as a derived table  and join with the actual table to get all the fields

```
    SELECT A.[Vendor Name], [Vendor No], [Item No], [Item Description], 
[Item Cost], [Quantity],B.Total
 from [SalesDB] A 
 inner join
    (SELECT [Vendor Name], SUM([Quantity]) AS Total
    FROM [SalesDB]
    WHERE [Vendor No] IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) 
    AND [Item Description] = 'bolts'
    Group By [Vendor Name])B
  on A.[Vendor Name]=B.[Vendor Name]
```

Comment: Hmm, it says syntax error, missing operator, in 'A.Total inner join'

Comment: Should the inner join be after the A `from [SalesDB] A inner join ...` ?

Answer (score 0):

**just an idea**

```
SELECT 
        [ItemID],
        SUM(ItemQty) as 'QTY',
        [ItemName] as 'ItemName',
        itemPrice as 'itemPrice',
        SUM(ItemTotalPrice) as  'Total'
    FROM
        [OrderDetails]
        inner join Orders
        on [OrderDetails].OrderID=Orders.OrderID
         where Orders.TableID != 4
    GROUP BY  ItemID, [ItemName],itemPrice order by ItemID
```